# exec() or system() on doxygen command returns me "Exiting"

Tags: php, system, exec, doxygen

Itry to run this script

`public function execDoxygen($doxyFile)
    {`

```
    $command = "doxygen $doxyFile";

    exec($command, $output);

    return $output;
}
```

and the outputs is "Exiting..."

if I run it separetely in a terminal with the same file it works well.

If I run exec("doxygen --help") it works correctly.

Why does it not work with a variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it contains spaces or other shell special characters, you may need to escape `$doxyFile` with [`escapeshellarg()`](http://de.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php) first.

Edit for the record, it was a permission problem. See the comments for details.

Comment: It is not that the commad seems correct 
see the dump:
command:  doxygen /home/guillaume/Documents/doxygen/Doxyfile-jmk <br />
output:  array('0'=>'Exiting...')
I think doxygen doesn't like to be executed via php...

Comment: Can you access the file directly from PHP using `fopen()` for example?

Comment: Yes, file_get_contents($doxyFile) returns me the content of file.

Comment: Maybe stderr doesn't show up in $output. Can you try `exec($command." 2>&1", $output);`

Comment: The result is:
<code>
array(
[0] =>
'Warning: the dot tool could not be found at /home/guillaume/Documents/doxygen/jmk/dot'
...
[1] =>
'Failed to open temporary file /home/guillaume/Documents/doxygen/jmk/doxygen_objdb_8350.tmp'
...
[2] =>
'Exiting...'
...
)
</code>

Comment: Ahh, that's better. Can it be that either PHP or Doxygen are not allowed to write into that directory? Can you make that directory writable or tell Doxygen to put its temporary files elswhere?

Comment: So i think I have the answer: the tool could not be found perhaps the environment var are not loaded... I will search in this way :-)

Comment: Oh yes it was a persmission problem, I do chown -R www-data: in the directory and now it works. I congratulate you :-).